# Uploading multipart with multer in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I have successfully uploaded files along with form fields to node server from my android app, however there seem to be no way for me to access the request body out of `multer's` loop, am only able to access the request body in `multer's` configuration, inside the `fileFilter` block. **The problem is** that this area is inside `multer's` loop when reading multiple files so my code logic cannot be written here.

`req.body` is `undefined` the area commented **AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA** where it should be accessed **before files are saved** but can be accessed inside the `fileFilter` block which is within the loop.

```js
let fs = require('fs');
let express = require('express');
let path = require('path');
let multer = require('multer');


// Set The Storage Engine
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './files/uploads/',
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, /*file.fieldname + '-' +*/ generateString(6) + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});
// Init Upload
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {fileSize: 1000000},
    fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
        let body = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
        //BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
        //THIS IS INSIDE A LOOP
        console.log("REQUEST BODY " + JSON.stringify(body));
        if (body.hasOwnProperty('opne')) {
            return cb('Stopped');
        } else {
            checkFileType(file, cb);
        }
    }
}).array('fileToUpload', 12);

// Check File Type
function checkFileType(file, cb) {
    
    // Allowed ext
    const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif|xlsx|xls/;
    // Check ext
    const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
    // Check mime
    const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
    console.log(file.mimetype);
    console.log(mimetype);
    console.log(extname);
    if (mimetype && extname) {
        return cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb('Error: Invalid file type!');
    }
}

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    upload(req, res, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(200).send('Failed ' + err)
        } else {
            if (req.files !== undefined || req.file !== undefined) {
                res.status(200).send('Successful')
            } else {
                res.status(200).send('Filed_')
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**QUESTION:** How can I access the form fields outside the loop **before files are saved**?.

**Reason:** Contents of the form fields contain validation data to determine whether the files should be saved, rejected or processed *(in cases of excel files)*.

Comment: Are you using `body-parser` package to get posted information on the route?

Comment: No, just the way I've posted it

Comment: install `body-parser` package that will help you to get field value.

Comment: great, let me do it.. with hopes